# Python conditional dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

Is there a reason why this list comp works:

```
N = 5
d = {0:100, 2:5}
[(dpidx,d[dpidx]) if dpidx in d else (dpidx,dpidx) for dpidx in range(N)]

[(0, 100), (1, 1), (2, 5), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
```

but this dict comp doesn't work? :

```
{dpidx:d[dpidx] if dpidx in d else dpidx:dpidx for dpidx in range(N)}

{dpidx:d[dpidx] if dpidx in d else dpidx:dpidx for dpidx in range(N)}
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm looking for:

```
{0: 100, 1: 1, 2: 5, 3: 3, 4: 4}
```

I thought I could just use a dict comp instead of a dict(list comp).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure "dictionary" comprehension is a thing...

Comment: Why not `{dpidx:d.get(dpidx,dpidx) for dpidx in range(N)}`?

Comment: Dictionary comprehensions are new in Python 3.x and 2.7.

Comment: Note that you could make your first list comp into a dict by doing `dict( (dpidx,d[dpidx]) if dpidx in d else (dpidx,dpidx) for dpidx in range(N) )` as that is so I question: Why the dict comp syntax was added?

Comment: @Dan D. because it is more concise and can be implemented in native code. Also because no lazy generator needs to be created, which would mean some overhead for managing it's state. Last but not least, it's just consequent to have equally powerful constructs for creating the most basic builtin collection types, lists and dicts.

Comment: @NiklasB. But when they redid list comps for Python 3, they turned them all into generators, removing the cheat that leaked variables out of list comps. In Python 2 terms they turned all `[ for in ]` into `list( for in )`. So all list comps in Python 3 create a generator. And I'd think that this is also the same for dict comps. So your statement that they don't require a _generator_ is false.

Comment: @Dan: if you just look at [the disassembly](http://pastie.org/3423951), you see that a dict comp is a special construct (this is Python3, it's very similar in Python2.7). Whether this is implemented as a generator internally is rather irrelevant, because implementation-specific. However, the timings speak for themselves and actually the performance difference even seems to be a bit higher in Py3k.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot repeat the key.  A dictionary comprehension has the form

```
{k: v for ...}
```

where `k` and `v` are expressions.  One (or both) of these expressions can be a conditional expression, which will give

```
{dpidx:d[dpidx] if dpidx in d else dpidx for dpidx in range(N)}
```

But `k: v` is not an expression in its own right.

An easier way to write this is

```
{dpidx:d.get(dpidx, dpidx) for dpidx in range(N)}
```

Comment: Of course, in this particular case you would write that as `{ dpidx: d.get(dpidx, dpidx) for dpidx in range(N) }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change dpidx:dpidx to just dpidx

Remember "d[dpidx] if dpidx in d else dpidx" means the value in the dictionary if there, otherwise the value of dpidx", it doesn't make sense having "otherwise the value of dpidx:dpidx"

```
d={1:2,3:5}
N=5

g={dpidx: d[dpidx] if dpidx in d else dpidx for dpidx in range(N)}

print g
>>>
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 5, 4: 4}
```